# Why do I get 0 as balance?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am using Solidity to deploy a contract to test network. Below is the full code. The deployment success but I always got 0 when run `getBalance` method.

I am using the test account which is running inside browser and the current account has 99.99 ethers. I don't understand why balance is always 0.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Leger {

    address owner;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return owner.balance;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: I just tested your code on Remix JS EVM, ganache-cli and Rinkeby test network and got correct result everytime. Could you provide more information / code  about your call to `getbalance` ?

Comment: oh, you are right. I can get the correct value. The problem is i read a wrong field which is 0 index.